# How can I use do.call() for more than two arguments?

Tags: r, do.call

Hitting some trouble when using do.call() with more than 2 variables.

```
ws.adjustments <- lapply(names(wdata@WS), function(name.ws) {
ws <- wdata@WS[,name.ws]
adjust.idx <- which(name.ws == sensors)
if(length(adjust.idx) == 0) {
  adjust.vec <- rep(F, nrow(wdata@WS))
} else if(length(adjust.idx) == 1) {
  adjust.vec <- excluded.periods[[adjust.idx]]
} else {
  adjust.vec <- do.call('|', excluded.periods[adjust.idx])
}
ws[adjust.vec] <- NA
return(ws)
```

})

When running the above code do.call() produces this error:

```
Error in `|`(c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  : 
  4 arguments passed to '|' which requires 2 
3.
do.call("|", excluded.periods[adjust.idx]) 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(names(wdata@WS), function(name.ws) {
    ws <- wdata@WS[, name.ws]
    adjust.idx <- which(name.ws == sensors)
    if (length(adjust.idx) == 0) { ...
```

How can I make do.call("|") use more than two variables?

excluded.periods = a Large List (4 elements)

It is used to remove dates specified in a config file.

Comment: I guess you need `Reduce` instead of `do.call`.

Comment: @nicola that worked it seems! any insight as to why do.call doesn't work for this particular scenario?